# Ajax Toolkit MaskedEditExtender different lengths on the same control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I live in Sao Paulo, Brazil. Here we've two different length for mobile phones based on code area. For example if my code area is (11) I've mobile phones with 9 numbers. For all other I've 8 numbers. How can use MaskedEditExtender to identify my code area and apply the correct mask?

I already have this:

```
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender 
 ID="Telefone_MaskedEditExtender" 
 runat="server" 
 TargetControlID="Telefone" 
 Mask="(99)9999-9999" 
 MaskType="Number" 
 ErrorTooltipEnabled="true" 
 MessageValidatorTip="true"
 ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false" />
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator 
 runat="server" 
 ControlExtender="Telefone_MaskedEditExtender" 
 ControlToValidate="Telefone" 
 IsValidEmpty="false" 
 EmptyValueMessage="O campo Telefone é obrigatório."
 EmptyValueBlurredText="*"
 InvalidValueBlurredMessage="*"
 InvalidValueMessage="Informe um número de Telefone válido."
 Display="Dynamic" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd fall to jQuery.  Evaluate the text in the `TextBox` for your area code, then use `.attr()` to change the `Mask` attribute of the `MaskedEditExtender`.

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Do you have an example? I've never used jQuery before. Also I didn't find any solution on Google.